# Chromium uses simple cache instead of "normal" cache

Tags: caching, puppeteer, chromium

I'm currently doing some research into the Chromium cache. There are disk cache and memory cache. I'm focussing on the disk cache. Here are 2 options:

1. The "normal" cache
   (https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack/disk-cache/)
2. The simple cache
   (https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack/disk-cache/very-simple-backend/)

I use puppeteer to control the browser and try some things out. On Windows everything is fine and Chromium just uses the "normal" cache. When I converted my code to docker it started using the simple cache, I can't figure out why. I've used Alpine, Node and Ubuntu as base image but all use simple cache.

So I went to investigate: did a fresh install of Ubuntu and Windows, ran Chromium on it. On Windows it uses the "normal" cache but on Ubuntu it uses the simple cache again.

I found that there used to be a flag "enable-simple-cache-backend" that you could pass to Chrome to force it to use the simple cache (it has been removed since). Simple cache is used on Android devices as stated by the the documentation but not on any other platform.

I'm wondering what makes chrome choose what type of cache system it deploys?

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for it, there are 3 operating systems that use the simple cache instead of the disk cache: Android, Linux based systems and Fuchsia.

See this bug report:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=611647&q=component%3AInternals%3ENetwork%3ECache%3ESimple/